# Set FontColor and HighlightedItem in ComboBox

Tags: wpf, combobox

I am trying to establish the color of my font and the highlighted color. With the font color I do not know how and the highlighted does not seem to work. It is already a list binded to the comboBox.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="selectCurrentLUT" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
          Height="21" Margin="2,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
          Width="121" FontSize="15" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif"
          ItemsSource="{Binding AllLUTLibraries}">
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}" Color="#404040"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Yellow" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Yellow" />
    </ComboBox.Resources>
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working fine after I copied/pasted it in a new WPF app.

Here is a commented version with each `SolidColorBrush` you would want to use.

```cs
<ComboBox x:Name="selectCurrentLUT" Width="100" Height="50" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}">
        <ComboBox.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}" Color="Red"/> <!-- Font color of all items -->
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}" Color="Green"/> <!-- Background color of all items -->
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Blue"/> <!-- Font color of the highlighted item -->
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Yellow"/> <!-- Background color of the highlighted item -->
        </ComboBox.Resources>
</ComboBox>
```

Hope it helps.